# Task not Serializable in Spark reading serialized input

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I am working on a Spark based Kafka Consumer that reads the data in Avro format.
Following, is the try catch code reading and processing the input.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import com.twitter.bijection.Injection;
import com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;

import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;

public class myKafkaConsumer{
  /**
  * Main function, entry point to the program.
  * @param args, takes the user-ids as the parameters, which 
  *will be treated as topics
  * in our case.
  */
  private String [] topics;
  private SparkConf sparkConf;
  private JavaStreamingContext jssc;

  public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{"
           + "\"type\":\"record\","
           + "\"name\":\"myrecord\","
           + "\"fields\":["
           + "  { \"name\":\"str1\", \"type\":\"string\" },"
           + "  { \"name\":\"int1\", \"type\":\"int\" }"
           + "]}";

  public static void main(String [] args){
    if(args.length < 1){
      System.err.println("Usage : myKafkaConsumber <topics/user-id>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    myKafkaConsumer bKC = new myKafkaConsumer(args);
    bKC.run();
 }

  /**
  * Constructor
  */
  private myKafkaConsumer(String [] topics){
    this.topics = topics;
    sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf = sparkConf.setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaFilterMessages");
    jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));
  }

  /**
  * run function, runs the entire program.
  * @param topics, a string array containing the topics to be read from
  * @return void
  */
  private void run(){
    HashSet<String> topicSet = new HashSet<String>();
     for(String topic : topics){
      topicSet.add(topic);
      System.out.println(topic);
    }
    HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "128.208.244.3:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    try{
      JavaPairInputDStream<String, byte[]> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        String.class,
        byte[].class,
        StringDecoder.class,
    DefaultDecoder.class,
    kafkaParams,
    topicSet
  );

  JavaDStream<String> avroRows = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, byte[]>, String>(){
    public String call(Tuple2<String, byte[]> tuple2){
        return testFunction(tuple2._2().toString());
    }
  });
  avroRows.print();
  jssc.start();
  jssc.awaitTermination();
}catch(Exception E){
  System.out.println(E.toString());
  E.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private static String testFunction(String str){
  System.out.println("Input String : " + str);
  return "Success";
}
}
```

The code compiles correctly, however, when I try to run the code on a Spark cluster I get **Task not Serializable** error. I tried removing the function and simply printing some text, still, the error persists.

P.S. I have checked printing the messages and found that they are correctly read.

Answer (score 0):

The print statement collects your RDD to the driver in order to print them on the screen. Such a task triggers serialization/deserialization of your data.

In order for your code to work, the records in the `avroRows` Dstream must be of a serializable type.

For example, it should work if you replace the avroRows definition by this :

```
JavaDStream<String> avroRows = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, byte[]>, String>(){
    public String call(Tuple2<String, byte[]> tuple2){
        return tuple2._2().toString();
    }
});
```

I just added a toString to your records because the String type is serializable (of course, it is not necessarily what you need, it is just an example).

Comment: I tried your suggestions and edited the avroRows variable, but the error still persists.

Comment: Where are you defining the function `functionToProcessByteArray` ? Is it a method of a not serializable class ?

Comment: I created a test function that only uses String class. So, the method uses serializable class. `private static String testFunction(String str){
    System.out.println("Input String : " + str);
     return "Success";`
 }

Comment: Can you post the whole code ? It should be easier to figure out what is missing

Comment: Added the whole code, please check if you could figure out the issue.